# Eclipse GWT Console Warnings

Tags: java, css, eclipse, gwt

I am building a GWT Java project in Eclipse Juno and when I run it I get the following Warning (it runs OK):

```
[WARN] 404 - GET /org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/Upload.css (127.0.0.1) 1405 bytes
Request headers
  Accept: text/css, */*
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/AwardTracker.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  Accept-Language: en-AU
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAAU; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
  DNT: 1
  Connection: keep-alive
Response headers
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
  Content-Length: 1405
```

I do not know why I get the error as I do not have Upload.css anywhere; or is that the reason? If it is the reason can I just copy an existing css and rename it? As I can not find a reference to it in the code why is it needed?

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: maybe other library that you are using is trying to get that css... maybe something related with Uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the `Upload.css` form [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/browse/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/bundle/Upload.css?spec=svn8c4547668b13ab606f0593ff3f913b14df9b817d&r=8c4547668b13ab606f0593ff3f913b14df9b817d) and put inside your project at the appropriate location.

May be you are using `gwtupload` bundle and internally it requires this CSS. Please check your jars and libraries again.

Comment: Hi Braj, I very much appreciate all the assistance you have provided. Now all I need to do is get the migration to my new Windows 8 PC fixed and I am right. Thank you very much, Glyn.